# quotation issues when mixing rails and javascript code

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to putting Rails and javascript code togetherto make a query string, here is the code:

```
link_to('CSV', '#', {:onclick => 'location.href="' + url_for(:controller => 'balances', :action => 'pc_form', :term => @fiscal_master.term, :format => 'csv') + '&month_index=" + \
jQuery("#month_index").val(); + "&dept_code=" + jQuery("#dept_code").val();', :id => "pc_csv", :class => 'dl_button' })
```

and it renders:

```
<a href="#" class="dl_button" id="pc_csv" onclick="location.href=&quot;/balances/pc_form?format=csv&amp;term=10&amp;month_index=&quot; + jQuery(&quot;#month_index&quot;).val(); + &quot;&amp;dept_code=&quot; + jQuery(&quot;#dept_code&quot;).val();">CSV</a>
```

When I click the button, the second query "dept_code" doesn't show up.
I'm guessing it's the quotation issue, but I don't know how to make it correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
link_to('CSV', '#', {:onclick => 'location.href="' + url_for(:controller => \'balances\', :action => \'pc_form\', :term => @fiscal_master.term, :format => \'csv\') + '&month_index=" + \
jQuery("#month_index").val(); + "&dept_code=" + jQuery("#dept_code").val();', :id => "pc_csv", :class => 'dl_button' })
```